# Allow guests to subscribe to specific taxonomy terms and send them weekly updates/notifications

Tags: emails, notifications

I would like to display a block to my visitors, where they can enter their email, name and a list of topics (taxonomy terms) they are interested in (e.g. "technology", "health", "science").

When subscribed, they should regularly receive updates/summaries via email, with new content in these topics.

I don't want users to necessarily sign up first, but also allow guests to subscribe to topics.

Is this possible with Drupal 8 natively or via plugin?
Or do I need to write my own plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews. This can be integrated with Views and Rules.